# Simulating a card has been confiscated after 3 incorrect PIN entries

Tags: vb.net

I am connecting to  database in Access that holds information on the card details.  One field is a 'confiscated' tick box that signals if a card's PIN number has been entered incorrectly 3 times.  I've managed to get the program to check the PIN entered is correct or not, and now I'm stuck trying to change the card's confiscated status in the database.  The card number is chosen from a drop down menu.  When a card is confiscated it should no longer appear in this combo box to the user. This is my code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class PinEntry

Public connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\ben\Documents\Programming\Year 2\Visual Studio\Assignment2\BankOfGlamorgan\EDP2011-BoG.mdb"
Friend connectionBG As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim commandCardNumber, commandPinNumber As New OleDbCommand()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim pinErrorCount, cardNumber, PIN As Integer
Dim oForm As Menu
Dim userInput As String

Private Sub PinEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connectionBG.ConnectionString = connectionString
    commandCardNumber.Connection = connectionBG
    commandCardNumber.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandCardNumber.CommandText = "SELECT cardNumber FROM ATMCards"
    commandPinNumber.Connection = connectionBG
    commandPinNumber.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandPinNumber.CommandText = "SELECT PIN FROM ATMCards WHERE cardNumber = ?"

    Try
        connectionBG.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = commandCardNumber
        da.Fill(ds, "ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DataSource = ds.Tables("ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DisplayMember = "cardNumber"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionBG.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnterPin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPin.Click
    cardNumber = Convert.ToInt16(cmbCardNumber.Text)
    commandPinNumber.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter())
    commandPinNumber.Parameters(0).Value = cardNumber

    Try
        connectionBG.Open()
        dr = commandPinNumber.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            PIN = dr.Item("PIN").ToString
        End While
        dr.Close()
        If PIN = userInput Then
            MsgBox("Correct PIN")
            oForm = New Menu()
            oForm.Show()
            oForm = Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect PIN")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionBG.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub txtPIN_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPIN.TextChanged
    userInput = txtPIN.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Couldn't you just select CardNumber where confiscated is null?

Comment: Is this just a test harness for a more secure app?  Please tell me my bank or anyone else's for that matter isn't using Access for this kind of stuff.  PLEASE.  Also, confiscated should probably be a bit field, and then you just query the bit field for records where confiscated = false.

Comment: Can you explain what is your question?

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to set the confiscated status?

Comment: @MauriceReeves it's a college assignment don't worry!

Comment: @Steve I want the confiscated field in the access database to change to true (tick box) if the PIN has been incorrectly entered 3 times in a row, and once confiscated, to not appear in the drop down menu (the card number that is)

Comment: @Tim when I tried that none of the cards appeared in the drop down menu

Comment: So you need a good chunk of code. First you need to save the number of tries. You could save them in a ViewState variable and check the value every time your user fails the PIN. If you reach the limit then you need to write the flag on your disk, and the query that loads the cardnumber should exclude the cards with the flag confiscated set to true

Comment: Do you get different results if you look for Confiscated not true/1?

Comment: besides the "Incorrect PIN" msg, you need to increment the error counter, then if it is > the max allowed, issue a SQL UPDATE to set the Confiscated flag in the DB.  You also need to modify the SQL source for the cbo to only show "open cards" (hint: use a WHERE clause) (more pedogical version of Steve's comment).

Comment: Oh man....`cardNumber` and `PIN` are both integers?  So what happens if either of them have any leading zeroes?